# How can I host my CSS and index.html file into my local server by using node

Tags: node.js

I just created a very simple landing page. I intended to practice my node skills and try to host the static website into my local server by using node. This is my file structure:

```
On my mac desktop. Inside NodeWebTest:

./assests
./css
./sass
index.html

But when I try to run it with my node code, my local server just running and cannot stop. What happen? How can I fix it?

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "./index.html"});


});


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You probably want `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` and get rid of your two `app.use` and `app.get`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much Roland!

Comment: Just want to ask why my previous code did not work? It seems like there is no syntax error...

Comment: `res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "./index.html"});` is not a complete response, its just the header. You would for example need to write: `res.send('hi');`. the other two static calls meant: serve the css and assets folder at `/`